# how to pass a .png file as parameter in clisp function

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

As I am new to lisp and the whole vecto package it provides I had this basic doubt.
I am using the function `radiant-lambda`

```
(defun radiant-lambda (file)
  (with-canvas (:width 80 :height 80) 
    (let ((font (get-font "times.ttf"))
      (step (/ pi 7)))
      (set-font font 40)
      (translate 45 45)
      (draw-centered-string 0 -10 #(#x3BB))
      (set-rgb-stroke 1 0 0)
      (centered-circle-path 0 0 35)
      (stroke)
      (set-rgba-stroke 0 0 1.0 0.5)
      (set-line-width 4)
      (dotimes (i 14)
    (with-graphics-state 
        (rotate (* i step))
      (move-to 30 0)
      (line-to 40 0)
      (stroke)))
      (save-png file))))
```

so how do I call this function?

Comment: What is your lisp implementation?

Comment: I am using CLisp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "general lisp" answer is that you call a function like this:

```
(radiant-lambda "/path/to/my/file.png")
```

and at the REPL prompt.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting this error "Bad magic value in font header: #x0A3B3B3B (expected #x00010000 or #x74727565 or #x74746366)
   [Condition of type ZPB-TTF::BAD-MAGIC]"
I am using clisp implementation in Emacs if that helps

Comment: @Gayathri: It appears that `times.ttf` is not a valid font file. Please ask a _separate_ question.

Comment: I did (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469918/bad-magic-value-in-font-header-x0a3b3b3b-expected-x00010000-or-x74727565-or) ,thanks