# Bad magic value in font header: #x0A3B3B3B (expected #x00010000 or #x74727565 or #x74746366) in clisp

Tags: vector, fonts, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am new to clisp and was trying to write a `vecto` function `radiant-lambda`:

```
(defun radiant-lambda (file)
  (with-canvas (:width 80 :height 80) 
    (let ((font (get-font "times.ttf"))
          (step (/ pi 7)))
      (set-font font 40)
      (translate 45 45)
      (draw-centered-string 0 -10 #(#x3BB))
      (set-rgb-stroke 1 0 0)
      (centered-circle-path 0 0 35)
      (stroke)
      (set-rgba-stroke 0 0 1.0 0.5)
      (set-line-width 4)
      (dotimes (i 14)
        (with-graphics-state 
          (rotate (* i step))
          (move-to 30 0)
          (line-to 40 0)
          (stroke)))
      (save-png file))))
```

But I got the error

> Bad magic value in font header: #x0A3B3B3B (expected #x00010000 or #x74727565 or #x74746366) [Condition of type ZPB-TTF::BAD-MAGIC].

I assumed while calling this function I had used the parameter incorrectly and had asked this question ([how to pass a .png file as parameter in clisp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455023/how-to-pass-a-png-file-as-parameter-in-clisp-function)), but apparently "times.ttf" font is the problem according one suggestion there.

Please let me know if how a font should be given here.

Comment: You might get a faster response by contacting the `vecto` developer directly.

Comment: How does `get-font` find "times.ttf"? Maybe use a path for an actual font file ?

Comment: A font's magic value ([head.magicNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/head)) is always to 0x5F0F3CF5. But it appears that error statement is actually talking about the font's [sfntVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff#organization-of-an-opentype-font) or [ttcTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff#font-collections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `times.ttf` file you are using is not actually a `ttf` file.  Where did you get it from?

Since the bytes `0x0A3B3B3B` translate to a newline followed by three semicola, I suspect that it is a renamed lisp file.